# Can I add a custom Id to a new element?

Tags: surveymonkey

**I would like to be the title of this question to be "Can I add a custom Id to a new question?" but the word 'question' is not allowed.**

Hi,

When I create a question in a survey, can I then 'attach' my own id as 'hidden content' to that question?

When I get all the questions/answers via the API, I would like to get my own id's and not (only) the id's that SurveyMonkey generated.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to put a custom identifier right now

Comment: That's too bad. Is there another way to match the question (the id of a question in SurveyMonkey)  to an id in our backend system?

Comment: I can't think of a good way to be honest (maybe a bad way to hide the ID in the description/title) - other than setting a new table/column on your end to have an external question ID.

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me